# How to start a listener from a Web Service? [Java Netbeans 6.7.1 & Tomcat 6.0.18]

Tags: java, web-services

My system has 3-4 web services which communicate with each other via UDP, so on start each Web Service needs to start a UDP listener thread, can this be done in the constructor of the Web Service itself?

I've done some reading (not sure if it is correct) and noticed that sometimes people refer to Web Services as "stateless" and mention that everytime a client connects it will create a new web service and thus run the constructor - but I want to run my constructor only a single time (when the service is deployed) and have it start my UDP listener only once ... and keep it listening even when no clients are connected...

Does that make any sense? How do people usually resolve this type of situation?

Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to run from inside an application server? Which one? Are you trying to write a UDP socket listener? How will you be launching your service? please provide more detail..

Comment: Zak - I'm really new at Web Services so let me try to answer...

I created a WebService (using NetBeans) which is a single .JAVA file that I can deploy/run from the IDE. Not sure what you mean by "application server"?

And yes, I have a thread that acts as a UDP socket listener (working already - as an RMI application).

As for how I'll be launching it - I didn't know I had much of a choice - right now I DEPLOY it (Netbeans IDE) - is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static initialization:

```
static {
  Listener.initialize();
}
```

Comment: Within the @WebService class itself?
But does this really mean that each time a client executes a method the default constructor is called again?

Comment: I guess in depends on the implementation - it is not unlikely that some pool is used. But better don't use default constructor in managed environment :)